# Update SSRS report parameters using custom ASP.NET controls

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a ASP.NET web app, which uses SSRS 2008 R2 on another machine in Native mode. The app has a page for generation reports created in SSRS.

I use my own custom controls for report parameters. After all the parameters are set,  the page generates the report using a hidden ReportViewer control.

Here is the page layout:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptParameters" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    <asp:Literal ID="label" runat="server"/>:
                </td>
                <td class="control">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbx" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
                    <my:tsJCalendar ID="calendar" runat="server" GeneratePostback="false" HasValidation="true" ErrorDisplay="None" CompareMessage="Date must be in valid 'mm/dd/yyyy' format!" Visible="false"/>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioList" runat="server" Visible="false"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnForDdl" runat="server"/>
                </td>
                <td width="22px"></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <td class="label">
                    <asp:Literal ID="label" runat="server"/>:
                </td>
                <td class="control">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbx" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
                    <my:tsJCalendar ID="calendar" runat="server" GeneratePostback="false" HasValidation="True" ErrorDisplay="None" CompareMessage="Date must be in valid 'mm/dd/yyyy' format!" Visible="false"/>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioList" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnForDdl" runat="server"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReports" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    ShowReportBody="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="false" ShowWaitControlCancelLink="false"
    AsyncRendering="false" Visible="false">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<hr />
<asp:Button ID="btnRun" runat="server" Text="Run Report" />
```

To generate custom parameter controls I use the repeater and show an appropriate control according by the report parameter type.

I am working with SSRS using its ReportingService2005 webservice. E.g. on the first page loading, I am getting report parameters using this code:

```
Private Function GetParameterReports(values As ParameterValue()) As ReportParameter()
    Dim rs As New ReportingService2005()
    rs.Credentials = New MyReportCredentials().NetworkCredentials

    Dim forRendering As Boolean = True
    Dim historyID As String = Nothing
    Dim credentials As DataSourceCredentials() = Nothing
    Dim paramInfos As ReportParameter() = rs.GetReportParameters(ReportPath, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials)

    Return paramInfos
End Function
```

The 'values' parameter is Nothing for the first time. However, if a parameter depends on other parameters, I do a postback, and pass report values to the report to get updated parameters, using the same GetParameterReports() method.

All the reports have a special field, 'user_id', which is the identifier of the logged in user. I must set this parameter manually in the code, and I am trying to do this by using 2 ways:

```
Dim Values As New List(Of ParameterValue)()
Dim singleUserParameter As New ParameterValue()
With singleUserParameter
    .Name = "user_id"
    .Value = Security.CurrentUserPeopleID
End With
Values.Add(singleUserParameter)
paramInfos = GetParameterReports(Values.ToArray)
```

and

```
Dim userIdParameter As New ReportParameter()
userIdParameter.DefaultValues = New String() {Security.CurrentUserPeopleID.ToString()}
userIdParameter.PromptUser = False
Dim rs As New ReportingService2005()
rs.Credentials = New MyReportCredentials().NetworkCredentials
rs.SetReportParameters(ReportPath, paramInfos)
paramInfos = GetParameterReports(Nothing)
```

Some of the report parameters depend on the 'user_id', but, unfortunately, after calling ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters() with the passed 'user_id' value, dependent parameters still don't have DefaultValues.

Could you help to understand whether I am doing something wrong while setting the report parameters values, or the reason is in how the SSRS report was created?